# Symfony 1.4, propel: when I try to save a record, it causes 500 error

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

All I have is:

```
   $rec = new Users();
    $rec->setUsername($username);
    $rec->setPassword(md5($password));
    $rec->setEmail($email);
    $rec->setRealname($rname);
   $rec->save();
```

the `save()` method triggers internal error (500) in symfony. The schema:

```
  users:
    _attributes:             { phpName: Users }
    ID:                      { type: INTEGER, size: '10', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, required: true }
    USERNAME:                { type: VARCHAR, size: '255', required: true, defaultValue: '' }
    PASSWORD:                { type: VARCHAR, size: '255', required: true, defaultValue: '' }
    EMAIL:                   { type: VARCHAR, size: '255', required: true, defaultValue: '' }
    REALNAME:                { type: VARCHAR, size: '255', required: false }
    STATUS_:                 { type: CHAR, required: true, defaultValue: '2' }
    NUMBEROFDELETEDAUCTIONS: { type: INTEGER, size: '10', required: true, defaultValue: '0' }
    NUMBEROFSUCCEEDAUCTIONS: { type: INTEGER, size: '10', required: true, defaultValue: '0' }
    _uniques:                { Index_USERNAME: [USERNAME] }
```

can anybody see the reason why?

Comment: There is no way to guess it with this information, could you append the stacktrace of maybe the apache error logs?

Comment: Sadly, its not the error of apache... its the brown screen of symfony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the dev environment so you can see more details about the error? Instead of http://www.blabla.com/index.php just use http://www.blabla.com/NAME_OF_YOUR_APP**_dev**.php (usually frontend_dev.php)

Comment: uhhh, first of all I did use the "echo $registrationForm->renderFormTag('registration/index');" format, still it didnt generate the target of form as /frontend_dev.php .......

Comment: just add id manually to the url (before submitting). In dev mode, it should keep it in all links generated with symfony's helper (link_to, url_for, etc)

Comment: Please read: http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/05-Configuring-Symfony#chapter_05_sub_what_is_an_environment

Answer (score 2):

Why are your schema uppercased?

What's the exception error message?

Have you tried with something like this?

```
$rec = new Users();
$rec->set('USERNAME', $username);
$rec->set('PASSWORD', md5($password));
...
$rec->save();
```

Anyway, there is a lot of symfony standards violation on this schema. Maybe it's imposed to you, but if it's not, please look at [some documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/03).

Comment: its just the usual symfony error: Something is broken
    Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
What's next......... no error message named

Comment: cool, after some debugging it say "username cant be null" but as you can see its set

Comment: are you sure $username is not empty?